# Having permission for read_stream, manage_notifications, publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, review

Okay, this is a rather specific question but I'll ask it here since I don't find any form on FB's website, this looks like it's the official place for FB support so here I am !

I am a part of a company which produces a unique web application for visually impaired people. Long story short, we take content from a bunch of websites and webservices and centralize everything in a single application, which is accessible, vocalized and controllable using the keyboard.

We would like to add a Facebook client to the application, using the Graph API. To make an acceptable client we would need "risky" permissions such as `read_stream` and `manage_notifications`, but I read that they are only granted for Facebook Clients written for a platform on which a FB client does not already exist.

So here is my question : do I have any chance to have any of these permissions granted, or am I wasting my time developing an app which will never be approved ? In order to submit the app for reviewing I must start to write it, and I wonder if it will be worth of my time.

Thanks :)

Comment: Both read_stream and manage_notifications have been deprecated and are not granted to anyone

Comment: I see. I guess there's nothing we can do about it ?

Comment: Correct. It was removed many versions ago

Comment: So why is it still in the documentation ? It gives false hopes about it (even tho it's clearly stated that they don't grant it to anyone)

Comment: They may be "available" in some old version that people that have an old app could use. But as you said. They are not granted to anyone so it doesn't matter

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer (you could maybe write one so I can upvote and accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WizKid stated, `read_stream` and `manage_notifications` are not granted to anyone but are kept in the documentation for legacy purposes.